# Best performance solution for SELECT ... FROM UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I have got two products tables, let's say `current_products` and `historical_products`, with the very same structure, and a key in the `product_code` field.

I have to search a list of product in these tables for further processing.

The trivial solution I've figured out is the following:

```
SELECT u.*
    , u.calculated_fields
    , t.other_fields
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM current_products
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM historical_products
) u
JOIN other_tables t
WHERE u.product_code = 'some_prodcut_code'
```

- PROS: DRY
- CONS: bad performance

The performance are not the best, so I would like to create a conditional query like this:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from current_products WHERE product_code = 'some_prodcut_code')
BEGIN
    SELECT u.*
        , u.calculated_fields
        , t.other_fields
    FROM current_products u
    JOIN other_tables t
    WHERE u.product_code = 'some_prodcut_code'
END
ELSE IF EXISTS (select * from historical_products WHERE product_code = 'some_prodcut_code')
BEGIN
    SELECT u.*
        , u.calculated_fields
        , t.other_fields
    FROM historical_products u
    JOIN other_tables t
    WHERE u.product_code = 'some_prodcut_code'
END
```

- PROS: better performance
- CONS: NOT DRY

**QUESTION**

Is there a third way?

Comment: What about in your 1st query, using where clauses with inner queries and filtering out the unwanted rows before union.

Comment: If you know there are no duplicates, or you do not care about duplicates, use `UNION ALL` instead, it will be faster.  Also, what @M.Ali said.  Filtering in the derived table will help as well.

Comment: Thanks to all. I have followed M.Ali advice, and it's performing well. M.Ali, please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

performance killing you because you are pulling all records from both table first, THEN applying the where condition... try changing to

```
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM current_products
       WHERE product_code = 'some_prodcut_code'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM historical_products
       WHERE product_code = 'some_prodcut_code'
) u
JOIN other_tables t
```

This way, the internal query can work against the indexes of the underlying products tables (presuming you HAVE an index on the product_code in the first position, or with other criteria you may want to also apply).